# Do Windows 10 Tablets that use the Cherry Trail run the normal x86 kernel and hence drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, tablet

Intel Cherry Trail Windows 10 tablets such as these examples: 
Jumper EZpad Mini 4 Tablet PC 8″

Do these tablets run the normal x86 version of Windows 10 with the standard kernel?

The reason I ask is I want to know if they will support installing an existing Windows 10 X86 FTDI USB/Serial driver.

edit: I understand that these will run "S Mode" which can be disabled. Providing S mode is disabled, can normal X86 drivers be installed?

Comment: those old Tablets don't run in S mode, so simply install any driver you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Providing S mode is disabled, can normal X86 drivers be installed?

Of course it can be disabled.  If you disable Windows S Mode, then of course, 32-bit and 64-bit drivers can be installed by you.

You already have some device drivers installed.  They were installed by the OEM when they created the Windows S image for the device.

Your version of Windows is running on Intel x86 hardware.  You didn’t specify if it’s a 32-bit or 64-bit installation, but remember all x64 hardware, is x86 hardware.